# Dryer Thermal Fuse Keeps Blowing

Tags: dryer

I have a Samsung DV42H5000ew and the thermal fuse (DC96-00887A) on the heating element housing has blown twice, most recently one a day after it was replaced.

After it blew the first time, I replaced the high limit thermostat (DC47-00018A) as well as the heating element (DC47-00019A).

Since it has blown again, I have tested the thermistor (DC32-00007A) and got 9.16 ohms.  My understanding that 10-11 ohms is normal - is my reading too low to the point that the thermistor is not regulating heat properly?

I tested the thermal fuse (DC47-00016A) on the blower (next to the thermistor) and it has continuity.

The vent and blower are extremely clean, figured I'd find some lint but did not.  I have great air flow at the vent cap.

I did discover that the dryer cord was incorrectly wired so far as the ground jump wire from the dryer was wired to the ground of the cord instead of the neutral terminal.  I have corrected this mis-wire - is it possible that, after 5 years of normal operation, this wiring issue caused problems that led to the thermal fuse on the heating element housing blowing?

At this point, I can't think of anything else that could be causing the dryer to overheat and blow the fuse.  Any suggestions on what else to check?

Answer (score 3):

The dryer has 2 thermistors, one near the heater element. One failure mode, if you have bad seals (they do wear out with age) on the blower or filter cover, such that colder air is sucked into the system, giving that thermistor a lower reading than actual, the control system will keep adding heat to bring up the temp. But, actual temp get hotter and blows the thermal fuse. Replace or repair blower and dryer filter cover seals.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

First check that the dryer vent system, from the air *intake*, through the dryer, and all the way outside through vent pipe and cap, is unobstructed. Overheating, as well as a fire, could be caused by limited airflow.

Check the heater itself. If coils in the heater element are bent over on each other or touching the shell, effectively shorting out part of the coil and drawing more current, it could cause overheating.

Also check that the heater is cycling on and off on any but the highest setting -- a stuck heat control contact could cause that.

Comment: Awesome airflow, everything is clear.  The heating element has no coils in contact with one another or the element housing. I believe there is likely a stuck contact on the motor or control board.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung DV45H7000E blew thermal fuse. replaced entire heater assy, 5 min, blew again.
Everthing clear, airflow good. Removed fan housing cover, wheel, drum movement ok.
Looked in fan housing cover, pulled out wad of lint. Replaced thermal fuse, day 1, hot, runs fine.